# AVR SPI stops clocking if the main loop contains a delay

Tags: avr, spi, atmega, delay

I have a weird issue here using an ATMega48:

```
#define F_CPU 8000000
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include "nrf24l01.h"

int main()
{
    initialize_nrf24l01();
    _delay_ms(200);
    //Enable AA
    nrf24l01_write_register(EN_AA, 0x01);
    //Enable data pipe 0
    nrf24l01_write_register(EN_RXADDR, 0x01);
    //Set address as 5 byte
    nrf24l01_write_register(SETUP_AW, 0x03);
    //Channel setup
    nrf24l01_write_register(RF_CH, 0x01);
    // Long range -0dB
    nrf24l01_write_register(RF_SETUP,0x07);
    //Siia tuleb teha aadressi asi

    uint8_t data;
    while(1) {
        data = nrf24l01_read_register(STATUS);
        //_delay_ms(500);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

and the nrf24l01.h

```
#ifndef NRF24L01_H_
#define NRF24L01_H_


// The register map of this file is derived from maniacbug (2007 Stefan Engelke <mbox@stefanengelke.de>) - https://github.com/maniacbug/RF24/blob/master/nRF24L01.h also licensed under MIT

/* Memory Map */
#define CONFIG      0x00
#define EN_AA       0x01
#define EN_RXADDR   0x02
#define SETUP_AW    0x03
#define SETUP_RETR  0x04
#define RF_CH       0x05
#define RF_SETUP    0x06
#define STATUS      0x07
#define OBSERVE_TX  0x08
#define CD          0x09
#define RX_ADDR_P0  0x0A
#define RX_ADDR_P1  0x0B
#define RX_ADDR_P2  0x0C
#define RX_ADDR_P3  0x0D
#define RX_ADDR_P4  0x0E
#define RX_ADDR_P5  0x0F
#define TX_ADDR     0x10
#define RX_PW_P0    0x11
#define RX_PW_P1    0x12
#define RX_PW_P2    0x13
#define RX_PW_P3    0x14
#define RX_PW_P4    0x15
#define RX_PW_P5    0x16
#define FIFO_STATUS 0x17
#define DYNPD       0x1C
#define FEATURE     0x1D

/* Bit Mnemonics */
#define MASK_RX_DR  6
#define MASK_TX_DS  5
#define MASK_MAX_RT 4
#define EN_CRC      3
#define CRCO        2
#define PWR_UP      1
#define PRIM_RX     0
#define ENAA_P5     5
#define ENAA_P4     4
#define ENAA_P3     3
#define ENAA_P2     2
#define ENAA_P1     1
#define ENAA_P0     0
#define ERX_P5      5
#define ERX_P4      4
#define ERX_P3      3
#define ERX_P2      2
#define ERX_P1      1
#define ERX_P0      0
#define AW          0
#define ARD         4
#define ARC         0
#define PLL_LOCK    4
#define RF_DR       3
#define RF_PWR      6
#define RX_DR       6
#define TX_DS       5
#define MAX_RT      4
#define RX_P_NO     1
#define TX_FULL     0
#define PLOS_CNT    4
#define ARC_CNT     0
#define TX_REUSE    6
#define FIFO_FULL   5
#define TX_EMPTY    4
#define RX_FULL     1
#define RX_EMPTY    0
#define DPL_P5      5
#define DPL_P4      4
#define DPL_P3      3
#define DPL_P2      2
#define DPL_P1      1
#define DPL_P0      0
#define EN_DPL      2
#define EN_ACK_PAY  1
#define EN_DYN_ACK  0


/* Instruction Mnemonics */
#define R_REGISTER    0x00
#define W_REGISTER    0x20
#define REGISTER_MASK 0x1F
#define ACTIVATE      0x50
#define R_RX_PL_WID   0x60
#define R_RX_PAYLOAD  0x61
#define W_TX_PAYLOAD  0xA0
#define W_ACK_PAYLOAD 0xA8
#define FLUSH_TX      0xE1
#define FLUSH_RX      0xE2
#define REUSE_TX_PL   0xE3
#define NOP           0xFF

/* Non-P omissions */
#define LNA_HCURR   0

/* P model memory Map */
#define RPD         0x09

/* P model bit Mnemonics */
#define RF_DR_LOW   5
#define RF_DR_HIGH  3
#define RF_PWR_LOW  1
#define RF_PWR_HIGH 2


uint8_t send_recieve_spi_byte(uint8_t data)
{
    // Load data into the buffer
    SPDR = data;
    //Wait until transmission complete
    while(!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF) ));

    // Return received data
    return(SPDR);
}

uint8_t nrf24l01_read_register(uint8_t reg) {
    _delay_us(10);
    PORTB &= ~(1 << PINB2);
    _delay_us(10);
    send_recieve_spi_byte(R_REGISTER+reg);
    _delay_us(10);
    reg = send_recieve_spi_byte(NOP);
    _delay_us(10);
    PORTB |= (1 << PINB2);
    return reg;
}

void nrf24l01_write_register(uint8_t reg, uint8_t data) {
    _delay_us(10);
    PORTB &= ~(1 << PINB2);
    _delay_us(10);
    send_recieve_spi_byte(W_REGISTER+reg);
    _delay_us(10);
    send_recieve_spi_byte(data);
    _delay_us(10);
    PORTB |= (1 << PINB2);
}


void initialize_nrf24l01() {
    //ce csn
    DDRB = (1 << DDB1) | (1 << DDB2) | (1 << DDB3) | (1 << DDB5);

    //CSN K�rgeks
    PORTB |= (1 << PINB2);

    SPCR=(1<<SPE)|(1<<MSTR)|(1<<SPR0);

}


#endif /* NRF24L01_H_ */
```

Programmed like this, everything works and I have SPI communication. If I now un-comment the delay in the while loop in the main file, `nrf24l01_read_register(STATUS);` line before it stops working to the point, where I get no SPI clock from the AVR even. I am driving SS as needed, and have it set as output, so that floating is not the problem.

If I toggle a pin right after the delay, it toggles with the correct timing, so F_CPU is correct. Fuses are default with CLKDIV8 turned off.

What could possibly be wrong here?

Comment: The best solution is just not to use delays. They are terrible in many many ways. You can use a timer to do delays with much better results. That said, have you looked at how the delay is implemented? Perhaps it blocks the SPI module in some way or messes with the registers that it is using.

Comment: Is there some interaction between the _delay_ms in the main loop and the _delay_us in the read function? Try using a timer, or timer-initiated interrupt to trigger the reading.

Comment: How do you know it is (not) working without having any debug output? @vini_i as long as the clock pin is not reconfigured in another library I see no way how the clock pulses can be suppressed. Even though you are absolutely right concerning your delay-policy there shouldn't be such a problem (hardware parallelism)

Comment: I suggest migrating this question to Arduino SE

Comment: @SimSon I have an oscillocope, which clearly shows the signals stopping + a logic analyzer which also shows nothing.

Comment: It might be a trigger issue. The actual transmission is way shorter (some microseconds) than those 500 milliseconds so you only can see this with a single-trigger.

Comment: @SimSon ho do you explain me then seeing the clock without the delay, without changing scope settings? And I've tried going to as low as 1 us on the timescale on the scope, to see nothing

Comment: Without the delay there will be a clock all over the time and you will see the clock pulses even without a trigger. When adding the delay there is no signal for ~99.9% of the time which looks like there was no signal at all on an oscilloscope without a single trigger. Without a digital memory oscilloscope there is almost no chance to see the clock